# What will be the best approach for a 2D game loading area assets on libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

What will be the best approach for a 2D game loading screens assets on a libgdx game?

My game has many areas, every area have a 1920*1080 jpg image, a few animations (image sequence) and audio. I can select all areas from a map by clicking on the area,

My idea is simple, every time I click the map I load the background 1920*1080 texture load the animations as `TextureRegion`, and the audio as music, 
when I select the map and click on other area, it will dispose the everything from the previous and load the new assets.

I was thinking on loading all areas at once using `assetmanager`, but even if all my assets are 50 megabytes, the memory on old android devices just crash,
my goal is to make fast transitions as possible when I change areas.

Please suggest.

Comment: Please revise the grammar in your post - it is extremely difficult to tell what exactly you are trying to do and what you are currently doing since there are just a bunch of comma-delimited thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

1. Combine all reusable sprites into 1 texture atlas.
2. Resize your sprites to a smaller resolution and avoid creating large texture atlas(I recommend to limit your texture atlas's size to 2048x2048 if you want to support older devices).
3. If you want to load/unload texture atlas every time the user changes map, it's best to use loading screen.
4. Music assets are streamed by Libgdx and not loaded in the memory. But you can lower the music's bitrate and sample rate to reduce its size.